# How to calculate integral of fourier series?

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I know how to integrate, but I can't understand how the integral of this fourier serie is calculated. my problem is with integral of the sigma.

fourier:

[image]

integral:

[image]

Can anyone say me how this integral is calculated?

Comment: You need to change the order of integration and summation.

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: $\int \sum = \sum \int$ under certain conditions. See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48119/criteria-for-swapping-integration-and-summation-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|\cos((2n-1)x)|\le 1$, the series is uniformly convergent and so you can exchange the order of integration and summation.

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^t (\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos((2n-1)x)}{(2n-1)^2} )dx &=& 
\int_0^t\frac{\pi}{2} dx-\int_0^t \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos((2n-1)x)}{(2n-1)^2} dx \\
&=& \frac{\pi}{2}t - \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^t \frac{\cos((2n-1)x)}{(2n-1)^2} dx \\
&=& \frac{\pi}{2}t - \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin((2n-1)t)}{(2n-1)^3}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: thanks. my problem is with the 3rd line. why (2n-1)^2 became (2n-1)^3 ? according to the integration rules I expect to see [(2n-1)^3]/3 in the integral

Comment: $\int_0^t \cos( \alpha x) dx = \frac{1}{\alpha} \sin (\alpha t)$.