# interchange the summation with the integration.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

We have

$$\int_0^\infty e^u h(u) \ du  = \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{u^k}{k!} h(u) \ du  
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \int_0^\infty u^kh(u) \ du$$

Under what conditions we can interchange the summation with the integration?!

Comment: Do you know anything about $h$?

Comment: [The Fubini–Tonelli theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48119/146687)

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two general sufficient conditions under which this is true:

1. If $h(u) \geq 0$ (almost) everywhere. In this case, this is just a consequence of the **monotone convergence theorem** applied to the sequence of partial sums $\sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac{u^k \cdot h(u)}{k!}$.
2. If $\int_0^\infty e^u \cdot |h(u)|\, du < \infty$. In this case, you can apply the **dominated convergence theorem** (to the same sequence as above) using the function $e^u \cdot |h(u)|$ as the dominating function.

As noted in the comments, these two statements above could also be obtained using the Fubini(-Tonelli) theorem, but I personally think that this is overkill.

BTW: Of course, we also have to assume that $h$ is measurable.