# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin xt \sin yt \cos zt}{t^2} \, dt$

Tags: improper-integrals

The problem is to evaluate the improper integral $I = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin xt \sin yt \cos zt}{t^2} dt$.

This can be written as $\int_0^{\infty} dt \int_0^y \frac{\sin xt \cos st \cos zt}{t} ds$, noting that $\int_0^y \cos(st) ds = \frac{\sin yt}{t}$.

I want to interchange the order of the two integrals for $I$ show that:

$$I = \int_0^{\infty} dt \int_0^y \frac{\sin xt \cos st \cos zt}{t} ds = \int_0^y ds \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin xt \cos st \cos zt}{t} dt$$

I know how to evaluate the second integral.  The integrand can be rewritten using the product to sum trigonometric identities to get:

$$f(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin xt \cos st \cos zt}{t} dt =
\frac14 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin((x+||s|-|z||)t)}{t} + \frac{\sin((x-||s|-|z||)t)}{t} +$$
$$\frac{\sin((x+||s|+|z||)t)}{t} + \frac{\sin((x-||s|+|z||)t)}{t} dt$$

It is well known that $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin xt}{t} dt =\frac{\pi}{2}$ sgn $x$, so we can provide an explicit expression for the integral.

In order to interchange the integrals for $I$, don't I have to show that $f(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin xt \cos st \cos zt}{t} dt$ converges uniformly on the interval {$0 \le s \le y$}.  But $ g(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin xt}{t} dt$ does not converge uniformly on any interval that contains $0$ and $f(s)$ contains four integrals of this form.

So I don't know how to show that I can interchange the order of the integrals or if it even valid to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the addition formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$, or more easily the relations $\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and $\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$, to show that

$$\matrix{4\sin(xt)\sin(yt)\cos(zt) &=& -\cos((x+y+z)t) + \cos((x-y-z)t) \\&&- \cos((x+y-z)t)+\cos((x-y+z)t)}$$

Using this the integral we are after can be written in terms of

$$I(w) \equiv \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(wt)-1}{t^2}{\rm d}t = |w|\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t^2}{\rm d}t = -\frac{\pi}{2}|w|$$

which is derived below as

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(xt)\sin(yt)\cos(zt)}{t^2}{\rm d}t = \frac{1}{4}\left[-I(x+y+z) + I(x-y-z) - I(x+y-z) + I(x-y+z)\right]\\ = \frac{\pi}{8}\left[\left| x+y+z\right|-\left| x-y-z\right|+\left| x+y-z\right| -\left| x-y+z\right| \right]$$

---

To compute the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t^2}{\rm d}t$ we generalize it by adding a $e^{-wt}$ term to the integrand, i.e. we study

$$f(w) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t^2}e^{-wt}{\rm d}t$$

We now expand $\cos(t)$ in a Taylor-series to get

$$f(w) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\int_0^\infty t^{2k-2}e^{-wt}{\rm d}t = w\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1/w^2)^k}{(2k)(2k-1)}$$

where I have used the definition of the [$\Gamma$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) to perform the middle integral. The justification for exchanging the summation and integration can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48119/criteria-for-swapping-integration-and-summation-order/48132#48132). Splitting $\frac{1}{2k(2k-1)}$ into partial fractions we get

$$f(w) = w\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1/w^2)^k}{2k-1} - w\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1/w^2)^k}{2k} = -w\arctan\left(\frac{1}{w}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(1 +\frac{1}{w^2}\right)$$

where we have used the Taylor-series for $\log(1+x)$ and $\arctan(x)$ to evaluate the sums. Taking the limit $w\to 0$ gives us the desired result $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ (using e.g. L'Hopitals).

Comment: Thank you for the solution!  It is far easier than what the textbook hints suggested.

Comment: Now I have to prove $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{cos(t)-1}{t^2}dt = -\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @larryh I have added a derivation of this result.

Comment: @laryyh Another way to show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t^2}\,dt=-\pi/2$ is to first write $\cos(t)-1=-2\sin^2(t)$ and then integrate by parts the integral $-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(t)}{t^2}\,dt$ with $u=\sin^2(t)$ and $v=-1/t$.  The resulting integral from IBP is $-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2t)}{t}\,dt$.  ;-)) - Mark

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I am learning a lot from asking questions in this forum.  I am working through my old Advanced Calculus book (Watson Fulks) from college doing almost all of the problems.  I am getting much more out of it than I did at college with your help.  I have two more chapters to go.

Comment: In order to solve$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{cos(t)-1}{t^2}dt = -\frac{\pi}{2}$, I was back to my original approach, interchanging the order of integration of the integrals:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{cos(t)-1}{t^2}dt = \int_0^{\infty} dt \int_0^1 -\frac{sin(st)}{t}ds = \int_0^1 ds \int_0^{\infty}-\frac{sin(st)}{t}dt = -\frac{\pi}2$$

Since $f(s) = \int_0^{\infty}-\frac{sin(st)}{t} dt$ is not continuous at $0$ and hence convergence is not uniform, the interchange of the order of integration is suspect even though it gives the correct answer.

Comment: I know the following is valid for $a > 0$:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \int_a^1 -\frac{sin(st)}{t}ds = \int_a^1 ds \int_0^{\infty}-\frac{sin(st)}{t}dt = -\frac{\pi}2(1-a)$$

In the limit, as $a \rightarrow 0$, I get the desired result.  Is this a valid proof?

Comment: I think this is valid if $f(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t) - \cos(at)}{t^2} dt= \int_0^{\infty} dt \int_a^1 -\frac{sin(st)}{t}ds $ is uniformly convergent on an interval of $a$ containing 0 (which it is).

Comment: @larryh I think you can do it like this (and avoid discussing uniform convergence)
$$\int_0^R \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(st)}{t}{\rm d}s{\rm d}t = \int_0^1\int_0^R \frac{\sin(st)}{t}{\rm d}t{\rm d}s = \frac{\int_0^R\text{S}(w){\rm d}w}{R}$$
where $\text{S}(w)=\int_0^w\frac{\sin(t)}{t}{\rm d}t$ and where I performed a substitution $w = Rs$ in the last integral. Since $\text{S}(w)$ converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $w\to \infty$ it's not hard to show that the limit is $\pi/2$ (e.g. this is a $\infty/\infty$ limit so L'Hopitals apply - or directly via a $\epsilon-N$ proof).

Comment: Well that problem took a few days to solve.  But the next one, which is similar, took less than half an hour to solve following the same pattern:  $= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin xt \sin yt \sin zt}{t^3} dt$ expressing the integral in terms of the integral $I(w) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(wt) - wt}{t^3} dt$